# odeint -(TypeError: can't convert expression to float ) - Importing expression into a function to perform odeint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, numerical-integration

**This is the error I get**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\Numerical Methods Problems\FreeFall.py", line 40, in <module>
    ans=odeint(vel,0,t)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 245, in odeint
    int(bool(tfirst)))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 325, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

And Here is my code - I am pretty new to coding and am learning to use it for numerical computation:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import math

def diff_cd(re_no):
    Re=Symbol('Re')
    expr=(24/Re)+(6/(1+(Re**0.5)))+0.4
    ans=diff(expr,Re).subs(Re,re_no)    
    return ans

def diff_re(k,u_no):
    u=Symbol('u')
    expr=k*u
    ans=diff(expr,u).subs(u,u_no)
    return ans    

ans = [diff_cd(20),diff_re(11,15)]

rhog=1.2
mug=1.872*(10**(-5))
a=0.3

u=Symbol('u')
pi=math.pi

k=(2*rhog*a/mug)
Re=k*u

p1=(rhog*pi*(a**2)*u*Re*((24/Re)+(6/(1+(Re**0.5)))+0.4))+(0.5*rhog*pi*(a**2)*(u**2)*diff_cd(Re)*diff_re(k,u))

ansfu=p1*(-1/24)


def vel(y,t):
    dudt = ansfu
    return dudt

t=np.linspace(1,100,100)
ans=odeint(vel,0,t)


print(ans)
```

I just need is to get an answer without this error. Also is there a way to do all this in a single function

Comment: It is not a good idea to mix `sympy` and `numpy/scipy`.  It can be done, with limits, using `sympy.lambdify`.   For a start, look at `vel(0,0)`.  Does that run?  Produce a number or numpy array?  Or a sympy expression?  `odeint` does not 'know' anything about `sympy`.  It expects `vel` to return a number.

Answer (score 1):

If I add a `print(vel(0,0))` before the `ode` call I get

```
-271.868595022194*u**2*(-3.97723522060237e-7*u**(-0.5)/(u**0.5 +
0.00509901951359279)**2 - 1.6224e-8/u**2) - 
543.737190044387*u**2*(0.4 + 6/(196.116135138184*u**0.5 + 1) + 0.000624/u)
```

That is, a `sympy` expression, not a number.  `odeint` cannot work with that!

`u` is defined as `Symbol`, and thus any python expression using it will also be a sympy expression.

Especially if you are new to coding, you should stick with one package or the other.  If defining the function symbolically, then use `sympy` and its own solvers.  But if a numeric solution of the kind that `scipy` produces is important, then define the function with python/numpy.  Don't try to mix sympy and numpy (without a lot more experience).

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj. Could you direct me to any python function where I could differentiate an expression wrt another expression without approaching mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

Old question but it seems you could've solved this problem using sympy's `lambdify` function. You'd do it like this:

```py
f = lambdify(x, x**2, modules=['scipy'])
```

now `f` is a lambda that you can use with scipy.